# Enable TLS 1.2 for SOAP WSDL Call in VB6

Tags: soap, vb6, tls1.2

We're using a VB6 application on Windows 7+ machines (we can't upgrade it just yet). We call several web services in the application like so:

```
Set objClient = CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
objClient.MSSoapInit gszEmailWebServiceURL
objClient.ConnectorProperty("Timeout") = 30000
strXMLResponse = objClient.GetEmails()
```

Soon, all of the web services we call are changing to only allow TLS 1.2 connections.

Is there any way to set the object to use TLS 1.2?

I know that in .NET, you can do this:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Is there something similar for VB6?

Also, I know that you can force the entire system to use TLS 1.2 by default, as specified here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in. I tested this on one of our VMs and it indeed works, but we'd have to do this on every one of our client workstations (100+) that use this application, and so I'm hoping there is a way to do it from within the app itself, as we already have auto-update functionality for the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a way to apply application updates on these workstations, but not a way to apply Microsoft updates?

Comment: I can apply the MS updates. Our IT department would just rather not if possible.